# TextBox value empty after styling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having problems taking out input value from my TextBox after styling.

Code of TextBox in xaml:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TaskTextBoxTheme}" x:Name="TaskTextBoxInput"/>
```

Code of TextBox style in a different file that is supposed to show watermark text:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="TaskTextBoxTheme">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="#404040">
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                <TextBox Margin="1"
                                     Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                     BorderThickness="0"
                                     Background="Transparent"
                                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                     Padding="5"
                                     FontSize="14"
                                     Foreground="White"
                                     x:Name="TaskTextBox"/>
                                <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                       Text="Enter your task here..."
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                       FontSize="14"
                                       Foreground="#606060">
                                    <TextBlock.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=TaskTextBox}" Value="">
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TextBlock.Style>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

And what I'm trying to do is take out the input value from TextBox and add it to database

```
if (TaskTextBoxInput.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                List listObject = new List()
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now,
                    Status = 0,
                    Task = TaskTextBoxInput.Text
                };

                db.Lists.Add(listObject);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Everything works perfectly fine without using style but with the style added TextBox value remains empty

Answer (score 0):

Your value text is stored in your style TextBox "TaskTextBox". You can take this value in this way:

```
        var textBox = FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(TaskTextBoxInput).ToList();
        var valueTextBox = textBox.First().Text;


    private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You nested a child TextBox in the original TextBox.
Visually, it works, but it is not available.
The element `<ScrollViewer x: Name =" PART_ContentHost "Focusable =" false "HorizontalScrollBarVisibility =" Hidden "VerticalScrollBarVisibility =" Hidden "/>` is used to determine the location of text entry in the TextBox style.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="TaskTextBoxTheme">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="#404040">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="1"
                                             BorderThickness="0"
                                             Background="Transparent"
                                             VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                             Padding="5"
                                             FontSize="14"
                                             Foreground="White"/>
                            <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                       Text="Enter your task here..."
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                       FontSize="14"
                                       Foreground="#606060">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=TaskTextBox}" Value="">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

Just in case, here is the full **default TextBox template**:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```